# Перенаправить GET запрос, javascript в ESPO CRM

Tags: get, crm

Пытаюсь подключить свою js-библиотеку в ESPO CRM, разраб молчит как партизан. Вобщем фишка в том, что у меня на странице есть js-код обращения к библиотеке Dadata, для автозаполнения полей адреса с их сервера. Вот он

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($){
  $(document).ready(
      function() {
    $("#address").suggestions({
        serviceUrl: "https://suggestions.dadata.ru/suggestions/api/4_1/rs",
        token: "f8967f3d558b271243e24c5e627dc6b82b7200eb",
        type: "ADDRESS",
        count: 5,
        /* Вызывается, когда пользователь выбирает одну из подсказок */
        onSelect: function(suggestion) {
            console.log(suggestion);
        }
    });
});
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Библиотеку я подключил, но в ESPO CRM это делается довольно неординарно, так что не уверен что правильно.
Итак сама проблема.
Обращение к serviceUrl: "https://suggestions.dadata.ru/suggestions/api/4_1/rs", ESPO CRM делает через API, и на странице консоль выдаёт такой запрос с 404-ой ошибкой - http://espo.myserver.ru/api/v1/https://suggestions.dadata.ru/suggestions/api/4_1/rs/status/address Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
Есть ли у кого нибудь опыт подключения библиотек в этой CRM?
Как избавится от префикса сервера в запросе?
Можно ли перенаправить этот запрос чтобы в начале какой-нибудь break был?

Comment: Ещё один момент, ESPO CRM работает на REST API. М.б. поэтому вызов скрипта в теле шаблона идёт через API, кто подскажет???